# How to write a new mode with hints for inhouse DSL in CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes

I'm trying to write an HTML editor using CodeMirror for some inhouse Domain Specific Language. I need help to write the mode and hints, where to start?

Is there any documentation other than the  Codemirror.net website?

Comment: You are already getting validation errors from DSL? Do want to display them in code mirror?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at some of the simple modes, such as [`mode/diff/diff.js`](http://codemirror.net/mode/diff/diff.js) and [`mode/properties/properties.js`](http://codemirror.net/mode/properties/properties.js). And of course, read the [manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi).

[edit]: Good news, this just got a lot easier. See http://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html